# sln and vssscc are always in my pending changes in tfs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs

My projects .sln & .vssscc are always in my pending changes and I can't understand why. When I compare them with my latest source there is no difference.

If I undo all my pending changes, and try to build the latest source, it will ask me if I want to save the changes to .sln if I check the pending changes again both files are displayed again even if I have made no other changes. has anyone came across this issue before? and how can it be solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by  deleting the project of my local hard drive, then got the latest again from TFS. The two files still showed up again, so I undid the changes directly on the Source Control Explorer window of VS2012